# Add 30 minutes to a time field on user input

Tags: javascript

I have a basic problem : when a user inputs the first part of a time window, the end time must be 30 minutes more than the first part.

Eg: when I type 09:00, the end time must be 09:30. If the user doesn't want this end time, he will change it manually.

[image]

This is what I've tried so far :

```
$( "#newOrderDeliveryTimeFrom" ).change(function() {
var newDateObj = moment($("#newOrderDeliveryTimeFrom").val()).add(30, 'm').toDate();
alert(newDateObj);
});
```

By the way, anyone knows a good JS plugin where time could be prompted in a nicer way than an HTML time field ? Because some of my users have the AM/PM displayed in the fields...

Thank you very much !

Comment: With your current solution, what is the result? This should be correct according to moment's docs. Have you debugged the value of you input?

Comment: The OP explicitly asks for an *alternative* to "time" input fields.

Comment: Why not stick with HTML time fields, but remove your "(24hrs)" label and _make use_ of the fact that 12- or 24-hr clock is selected (according to system locale) [on all major browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)? Make use of that feature.

Comment: The only alternative to a time field would be to use text fields or selects and then you would have to concat the strings into a time string manually.

Comment: @SandraWillford hello, thanks for your reply and sorry for the delay. The alert displays this :

localhost says
Invalid Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I've finally done it. I used a very basic jQuery plugin time picker. And this is my js code :

```
$('#newOrderDeliveryTimeFrom').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    dropdown: false,
    change:function(time){
        var element = $(this), text;
        var timepicker = element.timepicker();
        $('#newOrderDeliveryTimeTo').val(timepicker.format(new Date(time.getTime() + 30*60000)));
    }
});

$('#newOrderDeliveryTimeTo').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    dropdown: false
});
```